# Multiple FTP sites for one folder (IIS)

Tags: windows, iis, ftp, sftp

I want to use my existing FTP folder created on Windows Server IIS and make a new SFTP site for this folder while keeping old FTP up and running.
Why we need two (S)FTP servers for one folder? Because it's data is dynamically changing often and we do not want to manually copy data from one FTP folder, to another.
We could use only SFTP as our main server but as the existing clients are using FTP it will be a headache to support all the clients (because documentation for end users are never enough).

e.g.

```
ftp.example.com
```

and this folder consists of `/data/upload/`

I want to make same data to be accessed from SFTP
eg. `sftp.example.com`

Can I use multiple FTP sites for one folder on Windows server? If I do want to create SFTP server I guess OpenSSH will be my go. I just couldn't find the right answer for my question anywhere.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just try it out.

Create two IIS FTP sites that point to the same `Physical Path`.

This works fine for me during a quick test on IIS 10.

I don't see any reason, why this shouldn't work. I often do it with web sites, and it works for FTP sites as well.